# Ways to search long list of values SSRS parameter

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

[image]

Issue:
The report I am working with has Building parameter with 200+ unique values.  I am trying to figure out a way to allow users to search and find values they're interested in quick as possible (instead of scrolling and selecting one by one).

So far, I am using another prompt in which you can pass a string value, which goes through a split function to generate Building prompt.  If you don't pass anything, it selects all by default.

It works, but it still isn't ideal because it would include other values you may not be interested in.  Example:  I only wanted: 20500,20700,21400.

Question:
Is there a better way to go about this?
Is there a way to save selections? And then allowing users to select their "top 10 most used" selections?

I think its just easier to dump it in Excel and then use its filter ability, but users disagrees :).

Comment: I like your last sentence, personally...

Comment: That is the common practice to use a filter parameter (depends on how intelligently you use that.) to further filter dropdown list. so you are on right track. for other options, you need to look out of SSRS domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed, sometimes a quick export to Excel solves an issues that is complex in the report.  That being said...

**Top ten idea**: Considering that all executions of reports are stored in the ReportServer database as a [log table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155836(v=sql.100).aspx), you have the information about which parameters are the user's top picks if you have access to this database (I understand not everyone will have access in their organization).  In the past I've had SSAS data models built off this information so that we could analyze the information as well as feed it into report parameters for situations just like this.  You would query the execution log or data model, create an optional parameter that includes the top 10 and then filter by it if the user selects a value off it.

**Filter Parameter**: You have the concept of this already obviously and should be able to add more complex logic (preferably isolated in a stored procedure) to meet your requirements.  In the case of matching '205' to '20500', you need to pad each parameter value up to 5 characters with zeroes on the right side and match that against the left 5 characters of your building value.

**Save Selection**: I might get criticized for this one because I believe reporting should be a read and not write process, but this is something that I implemented in a scenario where SSRS **HAD** to be used and I was being pushed to find a solution. Pull your main dataset from a stored procedure that you will obviously be passing your filter parameter into and add another parameter for the user executing the query.  In the stored procedure before you return the results, do an upsert into a new UserLastParameter table to record the user's last value and then use this table to populate future parameter values.

Comment: I think I will try to look into auto populating last inputs for a specific user.  I do not mind doing the work, but I'm not truly seeing "time saving" benefit trying to replicate feature that is in Excel/BusinessObjects.

Comment: I think you have the right idea, but sometimes the man paying the bill gets to override best practices or common sense right? :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to satisfy users need simply by converting keyword prompt from text box to LOV by allowing to choose multiple values. By doing this, users can simply copy and paste data from email or excel spreadsheet.  It will also add comma automatically!  Who would have known!